# C++ Deep copy of dynamic array through assignment operator

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays, delete-operator

I am trying to copy a dynamically allocated array to an instance. My code seems to be copying the values over, but it also need to resize the array to match the "&other" size array.

A little info about the code: There are two classes at hand, one is "Movie" which takes a title, film-time, and director (all pointers) as private members. There is another called "MovieCollection" which is an array that stores each instance of "Movie" in a given index.

```
//These are private member variables:`

int ArrySize = 50; //There is another section of code that points to this and resizes if needed, I believe it needed a size at runtime though.

//Array to store instance of "movie"
Movie *movieArry = new Movie[ArrySize];

//This is assignment operator
const MovieCollection& operator=(const MovieCollection& other)
{ 
  delete []movieArray;
  int otherSizeArry = other.ArrySize;
  Movie* temp;
  temp = new Movie[otherSizeArry];

  for (int i = 0; i < otherSizeArry; i++)
  temp[i] = other.movieArry[i];

  return *this;
  delete []temp;
}
```

I used another function I wrote to resize the array while the instance is being created. For example, the instance I want to copy over has 10 indexes but the new instance I am trying to copy the values into still has a limit of 50. From what I understand I have to delete it because arrays cannot be resized, then copy the new size over (along with the values).

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advanced. Also, sorry if more code is required. I didn't want to give more than what was needed.

Comment: Just use a `std::vector`. There's no point trying to manually manage an array like this. Also there's multiple problems with the code, but it's hard to comment because it's not valid/compilable as posted. You're deleting movieArray *before* copying it (undefined behaviour and use-after-free), and trying to delete `temp` after returning, which never gets executed (leak), and you're never assigning the copied array to anything.

Comment: In the assignment operator, `movieArray` needs to be assigned to something after being deleted.     Such as `movieArray = temp` BEFORE the return statement.   Such things don't happen if you don't code them properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignment operator is implemented incorrectly.  It is freeing the `movieArray` array before allocating the new `temp` array.  If the allocation fails, the class will be left in a bad state.  And you are not assigning the `temp` array to `movieArray` before calling `return *this;` (the `delete []temp` is never reached, the compiler should have warned you about that).

The operator should look more like this instead:

```cpp
MovieCollection& operator=(const MovieCollection& other)
{ 
    if (&other != this)
    {
        int otherSizeArry = other.ArrySize;
        Movie* temp = new Movie[otherSizeArry];

        for (int i = 0; i < otherSizeArry; ++i) {
            temp[i] = other.movieArry[i];
        }
        // alternatively:
        // std::copy(other.movieArry, other.movieArry + otherSizeArry, temp);

        std::swap(movieArray, temp);
        ArrySize = otherSizeArry;

        delete[] temp;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

If your class has a copy constructor (and it should - if it does not, you need to add one), the implementation of the assignment operator can be greatly simplified:

```cpp
/*
MovieCollection(const MovieCollection& other)
{
    ArrySize = other.ArrySize;
    movieArray = new Movie[ArrySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < ArrySize; ++i) {
        movieArray[i] = other.movieArry[i];
    }
    // alternatively:
    // std::copy(other.movieArry, other.movieArry + ArrySize, movieArray);
}
*/

MovieCollection& operator=(const MovieCollection& other)
{ 
    if (&other != this)
    {
        MovieCollection temp(other);
        std::swap(movieArray, temp.movieArray);
        std::swap(ArrySize, temp.ArrySize);
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Remy! The explanation is greatly appreciated as I am still learning. I do have a question, why is "ArrySize = otherSizeArry" implemented at the end? Shouldn't the size of the array be established before the values are copied in? Or does it not matter?

Comment: @Brian I prefer to update the size after the pointer to the data is successfully updated. As long as the pointer still points to the old data, the size should reflect the old size